# Controlling the environ passed to child process by bash

Tags: bash, process, environment-variables

I am using x86_64 GNU/Linux with `bash`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    system("set > setc");                           // A subset of `$ set`

    return 0;
}
```

I can see the file setc contains a subset of `$ set`.
I am feeling curious as to know how the shell (parent process) decides what to supply to child process and what not to?
What if I want to supply more environ variables to child process? How one can control that?

Comment: Also on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/879999/ and on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609763/

Answer (score 1):

The shell builtin `set` shows all variables, not just those that have been exported to the environment.

If you want to add a variable to the environment, simply do `export variablename` in your shell.

Comment: My question is how to control the 'environment passing' from parent process (shell) to child process as from above code we can see that shell passes only a subset of environ to the child process. How to control that subset?

Comment: No, the shell doesn't pass only a subset of the environment; by definition the whole environment is passed; that's what the environment *is*. Try running `env` in your shell and compare that to `set`.

Comment: Yes! The shell does pass _only_ a subset of the shell's environment. At least that's what `man bash` says. While `env` refers to the subset of environ passed to a subprocess, `set` refers to all the variables in shell's environ.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, the way environment variables transit from program to program is through the [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) system call, which loads a new program image from disk. (This image replaces the current program; there's another system call, [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), which duplicates the current program; functions like `system` combine `fork`, `execve` and a few other system calls to launch a subprocess.) At this low level, a program can pass whatever it wants to the successor program.

However, most programs simply pass on the environment that they received when they started. Library functions like `system` read a global variables which is initialized to the program's initial environment; this global variable can be modified by other library functions such as `putenv`. If a program doesn't include code specifically designed to change the environment, it will transmit its environment to its subprocesses.

In your test, you used the shell command [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin). This command lists shell variables, which are a superset of environment variables. The shell exposes all of its environment variables as variables of the shell programming language; in addition, you can define more variables. The built-in command [`export`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export) takes the name of a shell variable as an argument and marks this variable as exported; variables marked as exported are added to the environment of subprocesses.

In an interactive shell, there are typically many shell variables which aren't exported. A freshly-started non-interactive shell has fewer. This is why you're seeing fewer variables from `system("set")` than you see in your interactive shell. If you looked at environment variables (with the command `env` or `export` with no argument) then you'd find the same (or perhaps a couple more, depending on the shell).

Answer (score 0):

After going through `man bash` got the whole picture. If I had read man before posting the question! BTW above one answer doesn't seem correct while other one falls short to clarify. So:

The shell has an execution environment, which consists of open files inherited by shell at invocation, the file creation mode mask, shell parameters inherited from the shell's parent in the environment etc. (For more details `man bash` COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT section.)
The builtins `declare` and `set` when invoked without arguments, spit out the values of all the variables (in name=value form) present in shell's environment. (Please note the output of `set` and `declare` comprises a part of shells' environment.)

Now when a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a *separate* execution environment that consists of the shell's open files, file creation mode mask, shell variables and functions marked for export (a subset of variables and functions in shell's environment) etc. If we try to fork this command then as Gilles said in above answer "If a program doesn't include code specifically designed to change the environment, it will transmit its environment to its subprocesses."

So when we try to execute above program, the program receives a subset of shell's environment. Then when we say system("set > setrc") the system() creates a child process (which is shell BTW) and then the child shell executes `set > setrc`. While doing so the program transmits it's environment (reduced version of parent shell's environ) to the child process (shell executing `set`). Now when `set > setrc` gets executed it prints the values of all the variables (in name=value form) present in invoking shell's environment which is a reduced version of parent shell's environ. That's why the reduced content of setrc.

### **Now How to control the environment being passed to a command by Bash**:

We can cotrol the parametes and functions to be passed by Bash to a command with the help of `export` and `declare -x`. (`man bash` ENVIRONMENT section.)

As other's have mentioned `export` and `env` so just to clarify : `export` and `env` (without arguments) prints the environment to be passed to subprocess (or command) and NOT shell's environ while `set` and `declare` spits out all the variables in *shell*'s environment. And that's why you can echo $VAR_NAME (any variable present in `set` or `declare` output inspite of it NOT being in `env` or `export` output).